# Interactive Resampling Slider, 1-24hrs, cannot get it to work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slider, resampling

I am a novice at coding, but I am trying to make this slider be able to choose the period I want to resample, instead of me having to manually type in the # of hours in the resampling portion of the code:

```
 #Resample subhourly data to 1 hourly graph (OUR STATIONS RECORD IN 10MIN INTERVALS, GFR IN 1HR, RESAMPLE FOR EASY COMPARISON. CAN TURN OFF)
    df1 = df1.resample('H').mean()
    df2 = df2.resample('H').mean()
    df3 = df3.resample('H').mean()
    df4 = df4.resample('H').mean()
    df5 = df5.resample('H').mean()
```

Right now, as you can see, it is set to just 1 Hour, if I do, ('3H'), it will resample to 3-hours. What I want to do, is be able to slide my slider 1-24 hours, and get it to resample the df accordingly. I am using the slider right now to choose the days, hours, period lengths, and variables I want to plot. I have tried the following:

```
df5 = df5.resample(resample_len+'H').mean()
df5 = df5.resample(resample_len + H).mean()
df5 = df5.resample('resample_len+H').mean()
df5 = df5.resample(resample_len+('H')).mean()
```

And many other ways. I have my resample_len defined, and I get no errors when I run the code, it just does not do any resampling... unless of course I just type in the # of hours I want, manually, and resample.

Any help would be much appreciated. You can see in the image below, I have the slider for resample_len, it is set at 12, but no resampling is being done. No errors tho.

[Image of the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9zgD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
resample_len = 3
df5 = df5.resample('%sH' %resample_len).mean()
```

or this:

```
df5 = df5.resample(str(resample_len) + 'H').mean()
```